# Relationships between different Java APIs

Tags: java, api

I found a list of Java APIs in [wikipedia's List_of_Java_APIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_APIs).

They all seem different from the document I usually look up, which is on this page
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

I don't understand the relationship between those two links. Are the list of apis introduced in wikipedia some other sets of java apis that are not included in the document I usually look up?

And where should I go to find the functions I can call using the api introduced in the wikipedia page? For example, when I googled Java Advanced Imaging, the closest result it gives is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/jai-142803.html  and I don't see a list of methods for me to use.

Answer (score 0):

The document you usually look up is the core java API - the main language specification. The Wikipedia list is a separate set of APIs which perform various more specialized functions, such as imaging (JAI) or object-oriented persistence (JDO). These other APIs do not ship with the core language and must be referenced separately via JAR files. As mentioned on the wiki page, there are multiple implementations for these APIs, so the location of the javadocs for them will vary by vendor.